# How do I add headers to the columns of a drop down list of a combo-box? (NOT a userform)

Tags: excel, vba

Right now I have a combo-box that has two columns in the drop down list. The left column displays a type of a material. The right column is a description of that material. What I would like to do is add headers when I open the drop down list from the combo-box.

I'm pretty sure this is possible because within the properties of the combo-box in the data category there is a property called "columnHeads" which either has a value of "yes" or "no". I toggled this to say "yes" however I don't see any way of changing or adding values to these headers. I assume this must be done from vba, but I was curious if there is a solution to this.

(I am not using a user form by the way which seems to be where the majority of questions about this are being asked)

I have tried specifying where I would like to place my header by providing a position, but this only added the header to the first position in the drop down list not the actual header.

**SUB THAT POPULATES THE COMBO-BOX**

*Here my code is just showing how I populate the array from the SQL database which I use to then populate the combo-Box in excel*

```
Public Sub AFCD_Column_Data(ByVal sql_col As String, _
                            ByVal sql_table As String)

' ... CODE...
' ... CODE...
' ... MORE CODE!

sqlrs.Open sqlcmd

    If Not sqlrs.EOF Then

        arr() = sqlrs.GetRows()

    End If

    Dim i As Integer

    Sheet1.ComboBox3.Clear
    Sheet1.ComboBox3.ListWidth = 400
    Sheet1.ComboBox3.ColumnHeads = True
    ' Sheet1.ComboBox3.Column(0,0) = "HEADER 1"

    For i = 0 To UBound(arr(), 2) ' the 2 refers to the 2nd dimension

        With Sheet1.ComboBox3
            .AddItem arr(0, i) ' adds the item / value to the first column
            .List(i, 1) = arr(0, i) + "(DESCRIPTION)" ' adds the description to the second column

        End With

    Next i

    sqlrs.Close
    sqlconxn.Close
    Exit Sub
```

Sorry I don't have an image of my combo-box and the drop down list. I couldn't figure out how to add the image, but all I am looking for is a combo-box where the drop down list displays two headers; followed by the rest of the data which I already have displayed.

Ex:

```
| "MATERIAL"  |  "DESCRIPTION" |
--------------------------------
| Titanium    |  "Description" |
| ...         |  ...           |
```

Comment: AFAIK you cannot edit the column headers, the value displayed will be chosen according to the way you fill the combobox. And if you add items manually, it will always be blank. (You have to use ListFillRange, and the header will be the cell just above)

Comment: Of course you can fill a range on some hidden sheet with your sql result, and then use this range as source to get the headers

Comment: Could "ListFillRange" work for an array? Maybe if I use the bounds of the array as the range? Or does it only add values from a range of cells within an excel sheet?